# What does laravel's Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder does?

Tags: laravel

I know that it's popularly used in cases of search and filters, But i have no idea what it is and what it returns and how it functions. Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's database query builder provides a convenient, fluent interface to creating and running database queries. It can be used to perform most database operations in your application and works on all supported database systems.

The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings.

Official Documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#introduction

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at this corse, https://laracasts.com/series/advanced-eloquent. I have already learnt a lot of laracasts. and the above link also is one of the best tutorial i have ever seen about Eloquent in laravel.